# How to define GridLayout to accept dynamic cols and rows in NativeScript

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have two GridDatas and two buttons in html. When user press Button1 I want to display gridData1 and when Button2 is pressed, I want do display gridData2. Here, rows and cols are not dynamic.

ts

```
gridData1 = [
        { label: 'Grid1_Label1', id: '-1' },
        { label: 'Grid1_Label2', id: '-2' }
    ];

    gridData2 = [
        { label: 'Grid1_Label1', id: '-1', extraProperty: 'Grid1_Label1_Extra1' },
        { label: 'Grid1_Label2', id: '-2', extraProperty: 'Grid1_Label1_Extra2' }
    ];

onButton1Tap(): void {
        console.log("Button1 was pressed");
    }

    onButton2Tap(): void {
        console.log("Button2 was pressed");
    }
```

html

```
<StackLayout>
    <Button text="Button1" (tap)="onButton1Tap()"></Button>
    <Button text="Button2" (tap)="onButton2Tap()"></Button>
    <GridLayout>
        <!--How should I implement here ?-->
    </GridLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

Here is play [link](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=l31Dpj). How do I define my GridLyout and display them dynamically?

Comment: Your question seems too broad. Your data format on gridData1 and gridData2 are different and there is no clue how you may want to format the rows / columns Or what all info you may want on screen Or why you would even need a GridLayout when you could stack the array of items.

Comment: I just want to display json data as it is on screen in a tabular manner. I am ok to use other layout if not GridLayout but only thing is json property will be decided by button click.

Comment: In face i have 9 reports to show on the screen so instead of creating 9 physical layouts, i am planning to use one layout and instead of click event i will use route parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I have updated your playground [here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=l31Dpj&v=2).
Add this in your html

```
<StackLayout >
<Button text="Button1" (tap)="onButton1Tap()"></Button>
<Button text="Button2" (tap)="onButton2Tap()"></Button>
<GridLayout rows="{{genRows()}}" [columns]="genCols()" height="400" width="400">
    <!--How should I implement here ?-->
    <Label *ngFor="let item of gridData; index as i; " row="{{item.row}}"
        col="{{item.col}}" text="{{item.label}}"></Label>
</GridLayout>
```

and in yout .ts

```
cols = '*';
    rowsCount = "*";

    gridData1 = [
        { label: 'Grid1_Label1', id: '-1', row: '0', col: '0' },
        { label: 'Grid1_Label2', id: '-2', row: '1', col: '0' },
        { label: 'Grid1_Label3', id: '-1', row: '2', col: '0' },
        { label: 'Grid1_Label4', id: '-2', row: '3', col: '0' }
    ];

    gridData2 = [
        { label: 'Grid1_Label1', id: '-1', extraProperty: 'Grid1_Label1_Extra1' },
        { label: 'Grid1_Label2', id: '-2', extraProperty: 'Grid1_Label1_Extra2' }
    ];

    constructor() {
    }

    genRows() {
        for (let i = 1; i < this.gridData1.length; i++) {
            this.cols += ",*";

        }
        return this.cols;
        // console.log(this.cols);
    }

    genCols() {
        for (let i = 1; i < this.gridData1.length; i++) {
            this.rowsCount += ",*";

        }
        return this.rowsCount;
    }
```

Comment: On button2 click, "ngFor="let item of gridData1;" needs to be changed to gridData2.

Comment: and on button click change  `this.gridData = this.gridData1;`

Comment: and don't forget to reset the `rowsCount` and `cols` on button clicks. https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=l31Dpj&v=4

Comment: Your example working fine with text="{{item.label}}" whereas if you see my gridData2, I have another total 3 fields to display. So what should I write in text="{{item.???}}" when property name and number of cols are dynamic?

Comment: in place of row: '0', I can use index value. But col: '0' is not applicable, as I should display all properties.

Comment: if you have 3 filels to display you can write  text="{{item.field 1 + item.field2}}"

Comment: and as columns are not applicable, don't use  `genCols() ` and you can avoid passing columns